# Writing code for raspberry pi to interact with a telegram bot

Tags: raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

I'm trying to write code to interact a telegram bot with raspberry pi. I want the raspberry pi to click a picture when a button is click and want the picture to automatically show up in the telegram bot. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question is not very well explained. What does a *"telegram bot with a raspberry pi"* look like? Where is the picture that the raspberry pi must click on - has it got a robotic arm to do the clicking?

Comment: Sorry for explaining the question well. The photo is clicked using the pins as a switch. "telegram bot with a raspberry pi" means that a telegram bot is interacting with a raspberry pi using the telegram bot api.